# C++ TCP CPU increase over Time(hours)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have the following code.
It serves around 10 Handheld Bar-code Scanners.
Everything its running fine except
It increase CPU usage over time in hours or sometimes days.
I rechecked all variables and checked with Process Explorer.
No memory leak,and threads/TCP connections behave as expected.
Please help.
Thank you.

```
#include "sql_serv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mingw.thread.h"
#include "str_functions.h"


void lf_client( SOCKET client)
{
     string LF ="\n\r";
     send (client,LF.c_str(),LF.size(),0);
}

string CONN_STR;
string CONN_STR_READ_ONLY;


 int overCPU( )
 {
   while(true)
     {
          Sleep(10*60000); // 10*60000  10 minutes

         if(SQL_SERV_SEL( "EXEC [CPU_OVER_LIMIT_RST_GET]",CONN_STR_READ_ONLY) == "RST")
         {
            INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV("EXEC [EXEC_OVER_CPU_LOG];",CONN_STR);
            Sleep(1500);
            WSACleanup();
            Sleep(1500);
            exit(0);
         }

     }
 }

 /* send(), recv(), closesocket() */

DWORD WINAPI receive_cmds(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    SOCKET current_client = (SOCKET)lpParam;

   bool list_ord = false;
  string ClearScreen= "[2J[H[A";
  string MENU_ALEX = "F2 Acasa\n\rF3 Log Off\n\r1 Comenzi\n\rL Listare Com\n\r2 Receptie\n\r3 UrcareRaft\n\r4 Cobor_Raft \n\r5 Consolid.Pal\n\r6 Schimb.Cant(S)\n\r7 Info Eticheta\n\r8 (S)/Master\n\r0 Inventar _";
  string builMasterMenu ="\r\n1=CloseMPal\r\n2-CancelMPal";
  string Beep2 ="";
  string Beep3 ="";
//******************** others**************


 // bool SN_STRICT =false;
  bool subRECEP =false;
  bool subSPLIT =false;
  bool UrcareRaft=false;
  bool Cobor_Raft=false;
  string  Cobor_Raft_MLL="";
  bool SN_CHANGE=false;
  bool INFO_ETICHETA= false;
  bool S_Per_Master= false;
  string S_Per_Master_MLL ="";

  //******************** others **************

 // bool SERIAL_KNOW =false;
  bool HOME_MENU= true;

  char recvbuf;
      // char buf[100] ;
      //  char sendData[256];
  int res;


    string check_conn= SQL_SERV_CHECK_CONNECTION(CONN_STR_READ_ONLY) ;
    send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(),ClearScreen.size(),0);
    string snd = check_conn + "\r\n*ServerV8*\r\nstd::thread\r\nCPU >__ RST\r\nSCAN_BADGE:\r\n";
    send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

    check_conn.clear();
    tempData.clear();


while(true) // LOOPER BEGIN
  {
    res = recv(current_client, &recvbuf, 1, 0);
    Sleep(15);
    //#Client Discon**********************
    if(res == 0)
    {
        if(ORDER_NR != "")
        {
        INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV( "UPDATE [ORDERS_SCAN_STAT] SET STATUS_ASSI_FREE='DISC' WHERE ORD_NR =" + ORDER_NR,
                                 CONN_STR);

        }
      closesocket(current_client);
      return 0;
    }

    if(recvbuf != 0) {tempData+=recvbuf;}

    // Restart App
    if (ReplaceString(tempData,"\n","")=="X000X0")
        {
             INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV("INSERT INTO [LOG_CPU_OVER_RSR] VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,'MANU_RS');",CONN_STR);

            if(ORDER_NR != "")
                {
                    INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV( "UPDATE [ORDERS_SCAN_STAT] SET STATUS_ASSI_FREE='DISC' WHERE ORD_NR =" + ORDER_NR,
                                         CONN_STR);
                }

            exit(0);
        }

    //! NUM FOR NORMAL PROC NEGIN
    if(tempData.length()>0 && HOME_MENU==true && tempData.length()<3 )
    {
      string menu_access =   ReplaceString( tempData,"\n","");
      menu_access =ReplaceString( menu_access,"\r","");
        //INVENTAR
        if (menu_access=="0")
         {
            Inventar=true;
            Inventar_LOC.clear();
            Inventar_MLL.clear();
            Inventar_SN.clear();
            ser_inDB=false;
            Inventar_COMP.clear();
            Inventar_QUNA.clear();

            menu_access.clear();
            send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
            string snd ="F2 Acasa:\r\nINVENTAR\r\n1 NEXT\r\nSCAN_LOC:\r\n";
            send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

            tempData.clear();
            HOME_MENU=false;
         }
         //if (menu_access=="0") INVENTAR END
      //SC_COMANDA
      if (menu_access=="1")
        {
          ORDER_SCAN =true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nSC_COMANDA\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          tempData.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        //if (menu_access=="1")  SC_COMANDA  END
        //RECEPTIE
        if (menu_access=="2")
        {
          subRECEP=true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nRECEPTIE\r\nSC_DOC_RECEPT\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          tempData.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        //if (menu_access=="2")  RECEPTIE END
        //URCARE LA LOC
        if (menu_access=="3")
        {
          UrcareRaft =true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string free_loc= SQL_SERV_SEL( "SELECT top 2 Adresa + ',' AS 'data()'  FROM FREE_LOC FOR XML PATH('')",
          CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nURCARE LA LOC\r\n" + free_loc + "\r\nSCAN_LOC:\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

          free_loc.clear();
          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        // if (menu_access=="3")  URCARE LA LOC  END
        //COBOR_PAL
        if (menu_access=="4")
        {
          Cobor_Raft =true;
          Cobor_Raft_MLL.clear();
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nCOBOR_PAL\r\nSCAN_MLL:\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        //if (menu_access=="4") COBOR_PAL END
        //TRANSF_CUTII  Consolid.Pal

        if (menu_access=="5")
        {
          subSPLIT = true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nTRANSF_CUTII\r\nSC_PALET_SURSA\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        //if (menu_access=="5") TRANSF_CUTII END
        //(S)CHIMB CANT
        if (menu_access=="6")
        {
          SN_CHANGE=true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\n(S)CHIMB CANT\r\nSCAN_SN:\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();

          HOME_MENU=false;
        }
        //if (menu_access=="6") (S)CHIMB CANT END
        //INFO_ETICH
        if (menu_access=="7")
         {
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nINFO_ETICH\r\nSCAN_ETICH\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

          INFO_ETICHETA = true;
          INFO_ETICHETA_SC_SOURCE="";
          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();

          HOME_MENU=false;
         }
         //if (menu_access=="7") INFO_ETICH END
        //"Nr(S)/Master"
        if (menu_access=="8")
         {
          S_Per_Master = true;
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nNr(S)/Master\r\nSCAN_ML\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
          S_Per_Master_MLL ="";
          tempData.clear();
          menu_access.clear();
          HOME_MENU=false;
         }
         //if (menu_access=="8") "Nr(S)/Master" END

    }
    //! NUM FOR NORMAL PROC END

    //! F KEYS BEGIN
    if(tempData.length()>2)
     {
      //F3 exit
      if ( tempData.length()>2 && tempData.substr(tempData.length()-3,3)=="OR")
      {

        ClearScreen.clear() ;
        MENU_ALEX .clear() ;
        builMasterMenu.clear() ;
        Beep2.clear();
        Beep3.clear();

        ORDER_SCAN =false;

        subRECEP =false;
        subSPLIT =false;
        UrcareRaft=false;
        Cobor_Raft=false;
        Cobor_Raft_MLL.clear();
        SN_CHANGE=false;
        S_Per_Master= false;


        S_Per_Master_MLL.clear();
        FULL_PAL_ORD = false;

        INFO_ETICHETA= false;
        INFO_ETICHETA_SC_SOURCE.clear();

        ORDER_SCAN_ML_FULL.clear();


        Profile .clear();
        COMP_ALEX .clear();
        Q_ALEX .clear();
        USER_ALEX.clear();
        LOC_ALEX.clear();
        MASTER_NR.clear();
        DN_TO .clear();

        subRECEP_CNTSN.clear();
        SERIAL_ALEX_RC.clear();


        subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.clear();
        subMLLOC_LOCAT.clear();
        subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf.clear();

        SPIT_SOURCE_PAL .clear();
        SPIT_DEST_PAL .clear();
        SPIT_DEST_PAL_LOCAT.clear();
        SPIT_SOURCE_PAL_LOCAT.clear();


        if(ORDER_NR != "")
        {
            INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV( "UPDATE [ORDERS_SCAN_STAT] SET STATUS_ASSI_FREE='DISC' WHERE ORD_NR =" + ORDER_NR,
                                 CONN_STR);
        }
        ORDER_NR .clear();

        ORDER_SCAN_SN_DELETER .clear();
        ORDER_SCAN_MLL .clear();
        id_RoW_ORDER .clear();
        NR_SN_ORD.clear();
        NR_SN_MLL.clear();
        ORDER_MAT_PER_MLL.clear();
        //TO_TPRD = "";

        SN_CHANGE_SER .clear();
        SN_CHANGE_QUAN .clear();

        Sn_INI_COUNT .clear();
        //SERIAL_KNOW =false;

        tempData.clear();


        send(current_client,"Good Bye\n",9,0);
        Sleep(1000);

        closesocket(current_client);
        return 0;
      }
     //F3 exit END

      //F2 Home
      if (tempData.length()>2 && tempData.substr(tempData.length()-3,3)=="OQ")
      {

/*
        Inventar=false;
        Inventar_LOC.clear();
        Inventar_MLL.clear();
        Inventar_SN.clear();
        ser_inDB=false;
        Inventar_COMP.clear();
        Inventar_QUNA.clear();
*/
        HOME_MENU =true;

        FULL_PAL_ORD = false;
        ORDER_SCAN =false;
        subRECEP =false;
        subSPLIT =false;
        UrcareRaft=false;
        Cobor_Raft=false;
        Cobor_Raft_MLL.clear();
        SN_CHANGE=false;
        S_Per_Master= false;


        S_Per_Master_MLL.clear();

        INFO_ETICHETA= false;
        INFO_ETICHETA_SC_SOURCE.clear();

        ORDER_SCAN_ML_FULL.clear();

        Profile .clear();
        COMP_ALEX .clear();
        Q_ALEX .clear();
        LOC_ALEX.clear();
        MASTER_NR.clear();
        DN_TO .clear();

        subRECEP_CNTSN.clear();
        SERIAL_ALEX_RC.clear();

        subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.clear();
        subMLLOC_LOCAT.clear();
        subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf.clear();

        SPIT_SOURCE_PAL .clear();
        SPIT_DEST_PAL .clear();
        SPIT_DEST_PAL_LOCAT.clear();
        SPIT_SOURCE_PAL_LOCAT.clear();

        if(ORDER_NR != "")
        {
            INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV( "UPDATE [ORDERS_SCAN_STAT] SET STATUS_ASSI_FREE='DISC' WHERE ORD_NR =" + ORDER_NR,
                                 CONN_STR);
        }
        ORDER_NR.clear();
        ORDER_SCAN_SN_DELETER .clear();
        ORDER_SCAN_MLL .clear();
        id_RoW_ORDER .clear();
        NR_SN_ORD.clear();
        NR_SN_MLL.clear();
        ORDER_MAT_PER_MLL.clear();
        //TO_TPRD.clear();

        SN_CHANGE_SER .clear();
        SN_CHANGE_QUAN .clear();

        Sn_INI_COUNT .clear();
        //SERIAL_KNOW =false;


        tempData.clear();
        send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
        string snd = MENU_ALEX + "\r\n";
        send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

        if (USER_ALEX=="")
        {
            send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(),ClearScreen.size(),0);

            string snd = "SCAN_BADGE:\r\n";
            send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();

        }
      }
      //F2 Home END
     }
     // if(tempData.length()>2)END
     //! F KEYS END
    // ENTER Key CR Action DO BEGIN
    if(recvbuf=='\r')
    {

        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "\n", "");
        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "\r", "");
        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "[A", "");
        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "[B", "");
        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "[C", "");
        ReplaceStringInPlace(tempData, "[D", "");

        // SEND LOGIN
        if ( USER_ALEX=="" && tempData.length()==0)
        {
          send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(),ClearScreen.size(),0);
          string snd = "ServerV8*\r\nstd::thread\r\nCPU >__ RST\r\nSCAN_BADGE:\r\n";
          send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
        }
        //if ( USER_ALEX=="" && tempData.length()==0) END

         //GET LOGIN
        if (USER_ALEX=="" && tempData.length()>0)
        {
           Profile= SQL_SERV_SEL("SELECT [role] FROM usersrole WHERE [USER]='" + tempData  + "';",
                          CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);
            if (Profile=="INV2")
            {
              USER_ALEX =tempData;
              string u_ex = SQL_SERV_SEL( "SELECT [FULLNAME] FROM  WHOISWHO WHERE [SHORT_ID] ='" + USER_ALEX + "';",CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);
              send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
              string snd = "Welcome::\r\n" + u_ex + "\r\n" + MENU_ALEX + "\r\n";
              send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
              u_ex.clear();
            }
            Profile.clear();
            tempData.clear();
          }
            //if (USER_ALEX=="" && tempData.length()>0) END

        //!MAIN PROFILE
        if (USER_ALEX!="")
        {   
//****************************OTHERS BEFORE***********************
               //! UrcareRaft BEGIN
            if (UrcareRaft==true )
            {
              // REQ subMLLOC_LOCAT BEGIN
                if (subMLLOC_LOCAT==""  && tempData.length()==0)
                {
                  send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                  string snd = "F2 Acasa:\r\nURCARE LA LOC\r\nSCAN_LOC:\r\n";
                  send (current_client, snd.c_str(), snd.size(),0); snd.clear();
                  tempData.clear();
                }
              // REQ subMLLOC_LOCAT END

              // GET CHECK subMLLOC_LOCAT BEGIN
              if (subMLLOC_LOCAT==""  && tempData.length()>0)
                {
                    string new_App ="";
                    new_App+=" SELECT  [LOC_ALEX_in] + CASE WHEN  COUNT (DISTINCT MLL)=0 THEN '' ELSE '@WARN' END ";
                    new_App+=" + CASE WHEN  COUNT (DISTINCT MLL) < (SELECT MAXNr FROM MAXNrOfMLLPerLOCAT)  THEN '' ELSE 'KO' END as MLLP ";
                    new_App+=" FROM  ALEX_EXT_LOCATII  LEFT JOIN ALEX_RECEP ON LOC_ALEX_in= LOCAT ";
                    new_App+=" WHERE [LOC_ALEX_in]='"+tempData+"' GROUP BY  LOC_ALEX_in ";

                    subMLLOC_LOCAT =SQL_SERV_SEL(new_App,CONN_STR_READ_ONLY) ;

                    new_App.clear();
                    std::size_t ERROR_IS = subMLLOC_LOCAT.find_first_of("KO");

                        if (static_cast<int>(ERROR_IS)>0)
                        {
                          subMLLOC_LOCAT ="MAXNRPAL=1";
                        }

                    std::size_t WARN_IS = subMLLOC_LOCAT.find_first_of("@");
                      if (static_cast<int>(WARN_IS)>0)
                      {
                        subMLLOC_LOCAT = subMLLOC_LOCAT.substr(0,WARN_IS);
                        send (current_client,Beep3.c_str(),Beep3.size(),0);
                      }
                    // Error
                    if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!=tempData)
                    {
                        send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                        send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                        send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
                        send (current_client,"SCAN_LOC:",9,0);lf_client(current_client);
                        send (current_client,subMLLOC_LOCAT.c_str(),subMLLOC_LOCAT.size(),0);
                        lf_client(current_client);
                        send (current_client,"Scan LOC", 8,0);
                        lf_client(current_client);
                        send (current_client,Beep2.c_str(), Beep2.size(),0);

                        tempData.clear();
                        subMLLOC_LOCAT.clear();
                    }
                      tempData.clear();
                }
                  // GET CHECK subMLLOC_LOCAT END

                  // REQ subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL BEGIN
                    if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!="" && subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL==""  && tempData.length()==0)
                        {
                            send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                            send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                            send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
                            send (current_client,subMLLOC_LOCAT.c_str(),subMLLOC_LOCAT.size(),0);

                            lf_client(current_client);
                            send (current_client,"SCAN_MLL:",9,0);
                            lf_client(current_client);
                        }
                  // REQ subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL END

                // GET CHECK subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL BEGIN L+
                if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!="" && subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL==""  && tempData.length()>0)
                {
                      string check_mll ="";
                      check_mll="SELECT TOP 1 DN_TO+'@RECTP_NO_COMPL'  FROM PENDING_RCP ";
                      check_mll+=" WHERE DN_TO =";
                      check_mll+="(SELECT TOP 1 DN_TO FROM ALEX_RECEP WHERE MLL ='"+tempData+"')";

                      string look_valid =SQL_SERV_SEL(check_mll,CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);
                      // Error
                      if (look_valid!="")
                      {
                          subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL=look_valid;
                      }
                        if (look_valid=="")  // OK check if mll in alex
                        {

                          subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL =SQL_SERV_SEL("SELECT TOP 1 MLL FROM ALEX_RECEP WHERE MLL='" + tempData + "';"
                                                              ,CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);

                          string on_loc = SQL_SERV_SEL( "SELECT TOP 1  LOCAT FROM ALEX_RECEP WHERE MLL='" + tempData + "';",CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);

                            if(on_loc!="0") subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL ="@DEJA IN LOCATIA@|" +on_loc+"|";
                            if(on_loc=="") subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL ="@ML NOK";

                          on_loc.clear();
                        }

                      check_mll.clear();
                      look_valid.clear();
                          // Error
                      if (subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL!=tempData )
                      {
                            send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                            send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                            send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);

                            send (current_client,"ML_NOK:",7,0);

                            ReplaceStringInPlace(subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL,"@","\r\n");
                            send (current_client,subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.c_str(),subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.size(),0);
                            lf_client(current_client);
                            lf_client(current_client);
                            send (current_client,"SCAN_MLL:",9,0);
                            lf_client(current_client);
                            subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.clear();

                            send (current_client,Beep2.c_str(), Beep2.size(),0);
                      }
                          tempData.clear();
                }

              // GET CHECK subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL END

                // REQ subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf BEGIN
              if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!="" && subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL!="" && subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf==""  && tempData.length()==0)
            {
              send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
              send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
              send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
              send (current_client,subMLLOC_LOCAT.c_str(),subMLLOC_LOCAT.size(),0);
              send (current_client,"\r\nConfirm LOC:\r\n",16,0);
              tempData.clear();
            }
                // REQ subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf END

              // GET subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf BEGIN
              if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!="" && subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL!="" && subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf==""  && tempData.length()>0)
              {
                  subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf =tempData;
                  // Error
                  if (subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf!= subMLLOC_LOCAT )
                  {
                    send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                    send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                    send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
                    send (current_client,subMLLOC_LOCAT.c_str(),subMLLOC_LOCAT.size(),0);
                    lf_client(current_client);
                    send (current_client,"\r\nSN_NO_MACH:\r\n",14,0);
                    send (current_client,"\r\nConfirm LOC:\r\n",16,0);
                    subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf.clear();
                    send (current_client,Beep2.c_str(), Beep2.size(),0);
                  }
                    tempData.clear();
              }
              // GET subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf END

            // FINISH  MOVE MASTER TO LOCATIONS  L+ BEGIN
            if (subMLLOC_LOCAT!="" && subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL!="" && subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf!=""  && tempData.length()==0)
                  {
                    string check_UP =INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV( "UPDATE ALEX_RECEP SET [LOCAT]='" + subMLLOC_LOCAT + "' WHERE [MLL]='"+ subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL + "';" ,
                    CONN_STR);
                    //TRASAB_V3
                    //string TRASAB_V3_URCA = "UPDATE ALEX_RECEP SET [LOCAT]= '" + subMLLOC_LOCAT + "' WHERE [MLL]= '" + subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL +"';\r\n";
                    string TRASAB_V3_URCA = "INSERT INTO TRASAB_V3_URCA ([M_DATE], [USER_], [SN], [MLL], [LOCAT]) \r\n";
                    TRASAB_V3_URCA += " SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '" + USER_ALEX + "', SN, '" + subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL  + "', '" + subMLLOC_LOCAT  + "'";
                    TRASAB_V3_URCA += " FROM ALEX_RECEP WHERE [MLL] = '"  + subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL + "'" ;
                    //TRASAB_V3 END

                      // Error
                      if ( check_UP !="OK")
                          {
                              send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                              send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                              send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
                              send (current_client,check_UP.c_str(),check_UP.size(),0);
                              send (current_client,"\r\nRetry\r\n",9,0);
                              send (current_client,"Scan LOC",8,0);
                                lf_client(current_client);
                              subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf.clear();

                              send (current_client,Beep2.c_str(), Beep2.size(),0);
                          }
                          // ok done
                      else {
                              string t_conf = subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL  + " DONE\r\n";
                              send (current_client,ClearScreen.c_str(), ClearScreen.size(),0);
                              send (current_client,"F2 Acasa:",8,0);lf_client(current_client);
                              send (current_client,"URCARE LA LOC",13,0);lf_client(current_client);
                                string free_loc= SQL_SERV_SEL( "SELECT top 2 Adresa + ',' AS 'data()'  FROM FREE_LOC order by SUBSTRING(Adresa,1,3)  FOR XML PATH('')",CONN_STR_READ_ONLY);
                              send (current_client,free_loc.c_str() ,free_loc.size(),0);lf_client(current_client);
                              free_loc.clear();

                              send (current_client,subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.c_str(),subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.size(),0);
                              send (current_client,check_UP.c_str(),check_UP.size(),0);
                              lf_client(current_client);
                              send (current_client,"Scan LOC",8,0);
                                    lf_client(current_client);
                              t_conf.clear();

                              subMLLOC_LOCAT.clear();
                              subMLLOC_MASTER_LABEL.clear();
                              subMLLOC_LOCAT_conf.clear();

                            INS_UPD_DEL_SQL_SERV(TRASAB_V3_URCA,CONN_STR);
                      }
                          TRASAB_V3_URCA.clear();
                        check_UP.clear();
                        tempData.clear();
                  }

            // FINISH  MOVE MASTER TO LOCATIONS  L+ END
            }
            //! UrcareRaft END

    //****************************AND SO ON ***********************
     }
        //! END MAIN PROFILE
 tempData.clear();
 }
    //if(recvbuf=='\r') END
     }
 //while(true) // LOOPER BEGIN
  } //DWORD WINAPI receive_cmdsPLUS(LPVOID lpParam) END




int main()
{
    printf("Starting up multi-threaded TCP server \r\n");
    FILE *fileStream_SQL; char fileText_SQL [240];
    fileStream_SQL = fopen ("PATH_sql.txt", "r");
    fgets (fileText_SQL, 240, fileStream_SQL);
    CONN_STR = fileText_SQL;
    CONN_STR_READ_ONLY =ReplaceString(CONN_STR,"Uid=sa;","Uid=alex_ro;");
    fileText_SQL[0] ='\0';
    fclose(fileStream_SQL);

 // our masterSocket(socket that listens for connections)
 SOCKET sock;

 // for our thread
 //DWORD thread;

 WSADATA wsaData;
 sockaddr_in server;

 // start winsock
 int ret = WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData); // use highest version of winsock avalible

 if(ret != 0)
 {
    return 0;
 }

 // fill in winsock struct ...
 server.sin_family=AF_INET;
 server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
 server.sin_port=htons(23); // listen on telnet port 23

 // create our socket
 sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

 if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
 {
    return 0;
 }

 // bind our socket to a port(port 23)
 if( bind(sock,(sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server)) !=0 )
 {
    return 0;
 }

 // listen for a connection
 if(listen(sock,5) != 0)
 {
    return 0;
 }

 printf("TCP server sin_port 23 \r\n");

 // socket that we snedzrecv data on
 SOCKET client;

 sockaddr_in from;
 int fromlen = sizeof(from);


 std::thread th_overCPU(overCPU);
th_overCPU.detach();

 // loop forever
  while ((client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen))!= INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
    Sleep(250);
    std::thread th_client(receive_cmds,(LPVOID)client);
    th_client.detach();

 }
 // shutdown winsock
 closesocket(sock);
 WSACleanup();

 // exit
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, it's important to try to reduce your problem to the smallest possible set of code that demonstrates the issue. Often, you will be able to solve the problem on your own at that point. If not, your reduced problem becomes easy to solve or write a bug report for. As you've written your question, it is too big and nobody is likely to be able to help you--or reuse the solution.

Comment: Thank you;If my code its to long the skeleton is from [link](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/26991-cc-how-to-code-a-multi-client-server-in-c-using-threads/) I have only replaced CreateThread(NULL, 0,receive_cmds,(LPVOID)client, 0, &thread);  with std::thread th_client(receive_cmds,(LPVOID)client);
    th_client.detach(); and added as buffer string  res = recv(current_client,buf,sizeof(buf),0);  because of telnet sending  byte/byte

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and then reduce your code to such an example. *In* the question.

Comment: hi I posted Skeleton of app.Hope it is minimal enough.

Comment: Offhand, I see several places in your `main()` where you seem to be ignoring errors. You might benefit from logging these errors instead (make sure to add a time stamp with the log). Use an existing logging library rather than creating your own. Then you can review the logs as performance degrades. You might be surprised at what you find.

Comment: Thank you.Its not the main,anyway i wilk try to reconfigure to Iocp.It migh be the host server it it a virtual mashine and today i saw some weird network usage.

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton of app

```
#include "sql_serv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mingw.thread.h"
#include "str_functions.h"

DWORD WINAPI receive_cmds(LPVOID lpParam);

int main()
{
 // our masterSocket(socket that listens for connections)
 SOCKET sock;
 WSADATA wsaData;
 sockaddr_in server;
 // start winsock
 int ret = WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData); // use highest version of winsock avalible
 if(ret != 0)
 {
    return 0;
 }

 // fill in winsock struct ...
 server.sin_family=AF_INET;
 server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
 server.sin_port=htons(23); // listen on telnet port 23
 // create our socket
 sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
 if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
 {
    return 0;
 }
 // bind our socket to a port(port 23)
 if( bind(sock,(sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server)) !=0 )
 {
    return 0;
 }
 // listen for a connection
 if(listen(sock,5) != 0)
 {
    return 0;
 }
 printf("TCP server sin_port 23 \r\n");
// socket that we sned recv data on
 SOCKET client;
 sockaddr_in from;
 int fromlen = sizeof(from);
 // loop forever
  while ((client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen))!= INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
    Sleep(250);
    std::thread th_client(receive_cmds,(LPVOID)client);
    th_client.detach();
 }
 // shutdown winsock
 closesocket(sock);
 WSACleanup();
 // exit
 return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI receive_cmds(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int res;
    char recvbuf;
    SOCKET current_client = (SOCKET)lpParam;
    string tempData;
    while(true) // LOOPER BEGIN
      {
        res = recv(current_client, &recvbuf, 1, 0);
        Sleep(15);
        //#Client Discon**********************
        if(res == 0)
        {
          closesocket(current_client);
          return 0;
        }

        if(recvbuf != 0) {tempData+=recvbuf;}
        // * A long code based on tempData content
      }
}
``
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, you need to delete this answer, and instead edit your question and put the code skeleton there. :)